# No sound after monitor sleeps with speakers through HDMI

Tags: sound, hdmi, lock-screen

I have my speakers hooked up to my monitor, which is supplied sound through HDMI from my video card (Nvidia). When the monitor sleeps, like when I lock my computer, the sound doesn't work after I wake it back up. If I open the sound settings control panel, the problem magically resolves. I assume this is because opening the sound settings polls the available sound devices again and re-establishes the connection.

It's a pain to have to open sound settings every time I unlock my computer. Is there a workaround or fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

## PulseAudio switching off HDMI sound on Suspend

This "undocumented feature" appeared with Ubuntu 16.04 and new version of PulseAudio 8.

Create a new file `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/tv-sound` and copy in:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "Going to $2..."
    # Place your pre suspend commands here, or `exit 0`
    # if no pre suspend action required
    sleep 1
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "Waking up from $2..."
    # Place your post suspend (resume) commands here, or `exit 0` 
    # if no post suspend action required
    sleep 2
    export PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH="/run/user/1000/pulse/"
    sudo -u rick -E pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
    ;;
esac
```

**NOTE:** replace user name `rick` (third line from the bottom) with your user name.

Then mark it executable with the command:

```
sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/tv-sound
```

An additional step might be required if `output:hdmi-stereo` (the device for most people) is different on your system.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for me. output:hdmi-stereo appears to be the right one using pacmd list-cards, and I did replace my username and make it executable. I tried running the pacmd command manually as well, and it didn't help.

Comment: Thanks dude, this command is exactly what I needed to get the sound working.